# Understanding scalar variables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I've inherited an SSRS report which I need some assistance in understanding how the scalar variable works as I just don't get it.

The stored procedure starts off as below and there is no issue running the stored procedure with the `@FromPeriod` and `@ToPeriod`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_SP_STOREDPROCEDURE]
     (@FromPeriod int, @ToPeriod Int) 
AS 
    set nocount on

    declare @v_FromPeriod int
    declare @v_ToPeriod int
    declare @cnt int, @periods int

    declare @v_periodbegindate datetime
    declare @v_YearBegindate datetime

ETC. ETC.
```

Next, I then have the other script which is run on an adhoc basis and this is the part I need help on:

```
declare @Period int
declare @PriorPeriod int

select @period = cur_per from tbm_Parms

if right(@Period, 2) <> '01'
begin
      set @PriorPeriod = @Period - 1
end

exec [_SP_STOREDPROCEDURE] @PriorPeriod, @PriorPeriod
```

How does this work?

My stored procedure has `@FromPeriod` and `@ToPeriod` defined, yet using the adhoc script it is passing `@PriorPeriod` instead.  It works perfectly but I don't understand how/why it works.

Any pearls of wisdom would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The stored procedure is using those parameters internally, it won't complain as long as you are passing correct value (no matter what is the parameter variable name is), even you can pass constant value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure "[dbo].[_SP_STOREDPROCEDURE]" simply applies the same value to both parameters.

Your parameters are:

```
    @FromPeriod int, @ToPeriod Int
```

You invoke with:

```
    exec [_SP_STOREDPROCEDURE] @PriorPeriod, @PriorPeriod
```

Assuming that @PriorPeriod = 5, that is just the same as:

```
    exec [_SP_STOREDPROCEDURE] 5, 5.
```

Now @FromPeriod contains 5. And @ToPeriod /also/ contains 5.

But you haven't given us enough code from _SP_STOREDPROCEDURE to explain why, according to you, that works perfectly. But I'm guessing that the answer is in the WHERE clause in your stored procedure.